# For setting up of protected video streaming channel with RTSP

Tags: encryption, rtsp

I have never deployed the systems of video monitoring. But now I'am going to deploy it with the next structure.

**Office:**

- static IP
- IP-cameras

**Home:**

- static IP
- NVR

*I decided to place NVR at home, because if an intruder breaks into the office, he will be able to take NVR away and then meaning of the video monitoring will be lost.*

A task to protect the channel between NVR and cameras appers in my structure. RTSP is supposed to be used.
I'm going to restrict an access to rtsp://... by office's networking equipment. Cameras will be available only from my home's IP. And then I can be sure, that no one can access to office's cameras.

My question: are the following statements true?

1. To decrypt the video stream packets on NVR side, the camera's password is used.
2. This password is transmitted from NVR to camera in plain text, when connection via RTSP is established.
3. Having this password, it is possible to view the video stream if the traffic between the NVR and the camera does sniffed.

I would be extremely grateful for a competent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its worth mentioning RTSP is a streaming control protocol, to control streaming servers. It defines how to package data to stream it and how both ends of the connection should behave to support the protocol. Thinking of it as a remote control is a very nice way to think of it - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43045354/334402.

RTP (Real Time Transport) protocol is what is used to actually stream the media streams.

Regular RTP is not encrypted end to end, which is what I think you are looking for here.

So someone 'sniffing' the stream will be able to view the audio and video stream without any need for a password.

It sounds like what you need for your use case is secure RTP - SRTP: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3711 (this is the spec but you can find overviews online with some quick searches also).

Many (or maybe most) leading IP security cameras will supporter SRTP now.

Comment: Thank you!
I'll take a look towards SRTP. It'll take a couple of weeks to study.
As I decide on the scheme of work, I will write an answer to this thread.